# How to stop the sfcc-inventory-pending_reservations-handle-orphaned job?

Tags: commerce-cloud, job

How to stop the `sfcc-inventory-pending_reservations-handle-orphaned` job?

It seems that it is a system job, so I was not able to find it in the `Administration` - `Jobs`.

The job is running infinitely and hinders the development on the sandbox, since it takes approximately 40 minutes to process a storefront request and reload the page. All the sandbox resources seem to be used solely for the job.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop system jobs. It looks like that job isn't even taking a second to execute every minute, so I don't think it is the source of your issue.

Likely the issue is that you've imported a catalog or inventory list that is too large for a Sandbox. Try reducing your import to a selection of representative products with representative inventory. (Representative in this case being a selection of products & inventory levels that cover all the use cases you'll need to test against during development)

You may want to check out the Catalog Reducer tool to help you achieve this: https://github.com/SalesforceCommerceCloud/catalog-reducer

If *that* doesn't help you, I suggest submitting a ticket to [SFCC B2C Support](https://support-demandware.force.com/customer/login).